# Select element by name

Tags: jquery, html

```html
<div class="fes-fields">
  <select name="departure_country[]" data-required="1" data-type="select">
    <option value="">- Chọn nước -</option>
    <option value="Mỹ">Mỹ</option>
    <option value="Úc">Úc</option>
    <option value="Pháp">Pháp</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The jQuery script to print log is

```
//Function executes on change of first select option field 
jQuery('[name="departure_country[]"]').change(function () {
    console.log("Selected");
}
```

The `console.log` does not print anything.

Comment: no error at all. so strange.

Comment: This isn't really a question about jquery, it's a question of how to validate your code and make sure you close your brackets! Always check the console when your code isn't working, in this case you would have been told the bracket is missing... though I do wonder how you manage to find out `console.log` doesn't print anything and didn't notice the error message right where you expected the output!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a brackets problem `);` is missing:

```js
//Function executes on change of first select option field 
jQuery('[name="departure_country[]"]').change(function () {
    console.log("Selected");
    $("#txt").html("Selected");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fes-fields">
    <select name="departure_country[]" data-required="1" data-type="select">
        <option value="">- Chọn nước -</option>
        <option value="Mỹ">Mỹ</option>                          
        <option value="Úc">Úc</option>                      
        <option value="Pháp">Pháp</option>          
    </select>
</div>
   <div id="txt"></div>
```

Comment: i replace my code by your code, but it is doesnt print log

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Is the jquery library loaded? Is the select being loaded dynamically?

Comment: There is no errors in console. jQuery is loaded because i can use datepicker.  "Is the select being loaded dynamically?"<--It is load from server.

Comment: unfortunately, it still does not work for me. Here is my javascript file. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27576887/Script1.js . Can you please take a look?

Comment: it is so strange that console.log("Select"); does not work. However, alert("Select"); works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that select element is loaded when you are trying to attach event to it. If the contents are static then wrap the event in document ready function

also make sure that you are closing the missing bracket `)` after change event:

```
$(function(){
 jQuery('[name="departure_country[]"]').change(function () {
  console.log("Selected");
 });
});
```